# Can Perl one-liner print matching pattern lines to a file and delete that lines in the original file?

Tags: perl

I have a `file1` which has lines

```
abc
dfg
hij
cab
```

I would like to match the pattern `ab` in `file1` and print to `file2`. After that delete those lines from `file1`. Then `file1` has the following lines

```
dfg
hij
```

and `file2` has lines

```
abc
cab
```

Currently, I am doing it with two lines of code

```
perl -ne '/ab/i && print' file1.csv > file2.csv
perl -n -i.bak -e 'print unless m/ab/' file1.csv
```

Can any one give me a one-liner Perl code?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `ed` instead:

```sh
$ rm file2.csv # Just in case it already exists
$ ed -s file1.csv <<'EOF'
g/ab/.W file2.csv\
d
w
EOF
```

(For every line matching the basic regular expression `ab`, append it to file2.csv and delete the line, and then finally write the modified buffer back to file1.csv).

But one simple perl one-liner:

```sh
$ perl -ni -e 'if (/ab/) { print STDERR } else { print }' file1.csv 2>file2.csv
```

This prints matching lines to standard error and uses the shell to redirect that to file2.csv, while modifying file1.csv in-place with just the non-matching lines.

Answer (score 2):

```sh
perl -i -ne'print { /ab/ ? *STDERR : select() } $_' file1.csv 2>file2.csv
```

But error messages end up in `file2.csv`.

These versions don't suffer from that problem:

```sh
perl -i -ne'
   BEGIN { open $fh, ">&=", 3; }
   print { /ab/ ? $fh : select() } $_;
' file1.csv 3>file2.csv
```

```sh
perl -i -ne'
   BEGIN { open $fh, ">", shift(@ARGV); }
   print { /ab/ ? $fh : select() } $_;
' file2.csv file1.csv
```